What is a lightweight way of testing Javax/Jakarta + RestEasy validation annotations?
Context :
Jakarta validation annotations seem straightforward at first glance but it's hard to understand the fine prints. The documentation has no examples and some people (including me) struggle with the corner cases, as shown by those stackOverflow questions:

How to use @Digits validation on integer value
Difference between @size(max = value ) and @min(value) and @max(value)
Etc.

It gets worse when used within RestEasy. Consider the following endpoint:
    @GET
    @Path("expectsLong")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public Response expectsLong(
        @NotNull @PositiveOrZero @QueryParam("searchValue") final Long searchValue)
    {
        return ok(searchValue);
    }

At first glance it looks air-tight.
For example GET /expectsLong?searchValue=-1 returns a nice HTTP 400 with a clear message
[PARAMETER]
[expectsLong.searchValue]
[must be greater than or equal to 0]
[-1]

The problem:
There's all sorts of annoying caveats that you won't know exist unless you try :
GET /expectsLong?searchValue=not_a_number
RestEasy does raise an exception but it's not caught and ends up as HTTP 500 or HTTP 404 depending on how you blundered. It's by design but it's very awkward.
My attempt:
I've decided to explore the scenarios manually, but it's impossible long because every change in the annotations calls for a rebuild, a redeploy, and if I'm unlucky even a server restart. That's not sustainable.
The question :
Is there a way of instantiating the overall RestEasy context (of even just one endpoint) in order to QUICKLY test exactly what HTTP status it will return, and with what payload?
Alternatively, is there some playground online? Any other out-of-the-box-thinking solution that you personally use on a regular basis?
More generally, is there a way of testing those behaviours in some unit tests? I wouldn't know how to instantiate the bare minimum skeleton to have both RestEasy and a fake annotated endpoint.

What container are you running in? If it's WildFly there are definitely easier options, but a redeploy might still be required. There is also the Jakarta REST SeBootstrap which might work. As for why the validation doesn't seem to work. RESTEasy must take a parameter value and turn it into a type before it can be run through validation.

One option then would be to use the wildfly-maven-plugin, assuming you're using Maven, and the dev goal. Another option would be to use a plugin in your IDE.
